# How to support popup menu in Android 2.1 version?

Tags: android

i am working on demo application.

have you any idea about popup menu in Android 2.1 version. actually working fine in android api level 11 and above..

reference url : http://www.sitepoint.com/build-intuitive-extensible-menus-in-android-with-java-and-xml-2/

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this. you just need a little bit of Animation and its done. :) It will give the exact feeling like a pop-up menu. I have done this before.

you need to use Relative layout for this purpose, because they can overlap on each other.

On click event of button, you need to show the View (relative layout holding a custom menu in this case) with an animation say bounce animation. again click on same button will hide the view again with an animation.

I wish I could post the code here but I have to search where I put my project. :P ;)

I hope it will give a little idea about a totally customized pop-up menu.

Comment: I want to use popup menu in ListView Row. so when click on row image popup menu display. if possible code than post here.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more? I have done this before. I would post my code here I guess it would help.

Comment: ListView having list of row.
When click on row icon or text. at that time show menu.seem like 


below link.

http://www.sitepoint.com/build-intuitive-extensible-menus-in-android-with-java-and-xml-2/

find public void CreatePopupMenu(View v) {}

this type of popup menu show.